# Difference between object+"" and object.toString()

Tags: java, string, tostring

What is the difference between these two codes: (the object is any random object)

```
Object object = anything;
String str = object+"";
```

and

```
Object object = anything;
String str = object.toString();
```

They both return the same `String`.

How do they performance? Which one is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decompile these examples using `javap -c` you will see that in first case

- `StringBuilder` will be created
- and it will `append(Object obj)`
- which internally will invoke `append(String.valueOf(obj));`
- which first will check for `null` reference.

So main difference in result of `null`

```
Object o = null;
System.out.println(o + ""); // result "null"
System.out.println(o.toString()); // throws NPE
```

If your data can't be `null` or you want to throw NPE you should use `toString()` for better performance.

If your data can be `null` and in this case result string should also be `"null"` `String.valueOf(object)` will give you better performance than `object+""`.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is equivalent to:

```
Object object = anything;
String str = new StringBuilder().append(object).toString();
```

whereas the second is just a plain `toString()` call. The performance difference is likely to be negligible, but the second will almost certainly be marginally faster because it doesn't use an unnecessary `StringBuilder`. Generally, prefer the second approach.